# Write corpus and vector to a csv file in R

Tags: r, csv, corpus

```
dat <- read.csv("file.csv",header=F)$V2
doc.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(dat))
....
doc.corpus <- tm_map(doc.corpus, stripWhitespace)
sent <- ""
for(i in 2:length(doc.corpus)){
    sent[i] <- get_sentiment(get_sentences(as.character(doc.corpus[i])))
}
sent[1] = "sentiment"
```

I have to write sentiment and doc.corpus into a csv file as two columns in R. If it was just sent I would have done something like write.csv(sent,file = "MyData.csv") this. But how should I write a corpus to csv file.

Answer (score 0):

dataframe <- data.frame(text=sapply(doc.corpus, identity),stringsAsFactors=F)